# How to download a mms stream with G2M4 video?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming, mencoder, gotomeeting

I have found that Gotomeeting recorded webinars are streamed as MMS streams.
It is well known that MMS streams can be downloaded/saved. For instance VLC has a corresponding option in the *Open Network Stream* dialog.

After a webinar attendees receive a link that after certain manipulations leads to an ASX URL. The ASX (Advanced Stream Redirector) has a simple structure

```
<ASX VERSION="3.0">
 <ENTRY>
  <REF HREF="mms://[...].akamaistream.net/[...].wmv" />
 </ENTRY>
</ASX>
```

The stream is packaged in the Windows Media Video format. Video is encoded as G2M4 (a gotomeeting format) and Audio is encoded as DivX v2.

Unfortunately on my machines this G2M4 codec is not available neither in Windows Media Player and Media Player Classic on Windows 7, nor in VLC on my Linux machine.

I am sure `mencoder` would have no problem saving this `mms` stream and posted my solution that uses it on [Gotomeeting community board](https://community.gotomeeting.com/gotomeeting/topics/download_recorded_webinar_instead_of_streaming).

So my question is twofold. How do I get the G2M4 Codec for use with GUI tools such as VLC or Windows Media Player, or are there ways to save a stream into a file that do not involve the use of tools such as `mencoder` that are not always available and are considered complicated by many users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really have two options. Personally, I use `Option 2` and a variance of it. I created a C#.NET service that will monitor a folder and will transcode any videos in that folder. Once a successful transcode has occured, it will move the video into a holding tank. The holding tank will upload the video to a LMS site I made. The LMS site will then capture the video uploaded and transcode it with FFMPEG to MP4, WEBM and OGG formats so that they can be streamed using HTML5.

### Option 1 - Download the GTM Codec

You can download the codec for GTM from https://www3.gotomeeting.com/codec. Installing this Codec should allow you to view the GTM video from within Windows Media Player on Windows 7.

### Option 2 - Transcode and stripe the GTM Codec

Download and install GTM software. This will by default include a transcoder application that can strip the GTM Codec from the video. GTM Software can be downloaded from https://global.gotomeeting.com/meeting/host.

You can create a converter.bat file and paste in the below code. Save this to your desktop. Once you have done this, you can drag and drop the GTM Encoded Video onto the `converter.bat` file.

```
@echo off
if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%XXX"=="XXX" (
set "ProgRoot=%ProgramFiles%"
) else (
set "ProgRoot=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
)
echo ***************************************
echo * To determine the GoToMeeting build, *
echo * Right-click on the GoToMeeting icon *
echo * in the system tray and select About *
echo ***************************************
SET /P build=Enter the GoToMeeting build number (Example: 457, 723, 799, etc):
"%ProgRoot%\Citrix\GoToMeeting\%build%\g2mtranscoder.exe" source=%~1
```

It will prompt you for your Build Number which can be found by hovering over the GTM icon in your system tray.

[image]

Comment: That was a type-o on my part. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Recent FFmpeg can (mostly?) decode Go2Meeting G2M4, but I'm not sure if [these G2M4 samples](http://samples.ffmpeg.org/V-codecs/G2M4/) only had 1 or 2 slides to display or if the decoding is not working as expected.

Recent builds of `ffmpeg` are available via links on the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.

The [MMSH](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#mmsh) and [MMST](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#mmst) protocols are supported, so you may be able to use `ffmpeg` to re-encode from the ASX URL:

```
$ ffmpeg -i mmsh://[...].akamaistream.net/[...].wmv -codec:v libx264 \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

Worth a try at least.

Also see:

- [GoToMeeting Codec Information](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=GoToMeeting_Codec)
- [FFmpeg H.264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)
- [FFmpeg AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)

Comment: Sadly I get `mms://a47[...snip...]a0.wmv: Protocol not found` with ffmpeg 2.3.3 on a Mac :(

Comment: @Ashley Try replacing `mms://` by `mmsh://`. (see e.g. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/998)